# Extracting emails from a file and writing them to another file

Tags: python, regex, csv, linux, email

The code below works fine for me.  Is there any way that I can improve this code more? Note: delimiter is single whitespace only for email address.

### getmail.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

handleone = open("scratchmail.txt", "r")
f1 = handleone.readlines()

handletwo = open("mailout.txt", "a+")

match_list = [ ]   

for ArrayItem in f1:

    match_list = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', ArrayItem)

    if(len(match_list)>0):

         handletwo.write(match_list[0]+"\r\n")
```

Input file **scratchmail.txt**:

```
tickets.cgi:5141|5141Z4063442957942364067088508|1219588377|1219588377||PND||abc@AABBCC.com|Mjpqafml|JgALKGXCuasMph|
tickets.cgi:358236|358236Z24989798132452492828304439|1433071308|1433071308||PND||xyz.abc@example.com|Edison|CpwxPARuQaqPR|
tickets.cgi:86805|86805Z25422507290694218605033173|1232345784|1232345784||PND||pytest@test.com|Agfaodki|jPdSNVlbXi|
…
```

Output file **mailout.txt**:

```
abc@AABBCC.com
xyz.abc@example.com
pytest@test.com
```

Comment: Or, you know, you could use *nix tools, e.g. `cut -d \| -f 8 scratchmail.txt >> mailout.txt`.

Comment: yeah, i tried with cut and awk -F'|' '{ print $8 }'  input.txt >>mailout.txt they both work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Working with file handles

You should always close the file handles that you open.
You didn't close any of them.
In addition,
you should use `with open(...) as ...` syntax when working with files,
so that they will be automatically closed when leaving the scope.

#### Checking if a list is empty

There is a much simpler way to check if a list is empty, instead of this:

> ```
> if(len(match_list)>0):
> ```

The Pythonic way to write is simply this:

```
if match_list:
```

#### Unnecessary initializations and data storage

There's no need to initialize `match_list` before the loops.
You reassign it anyway inside.

You don't need to store all the lines from the first file into a list.
You can process the input line by line and write output line by line.
That can save a lot of memory, as you only need to keep one line in memory at a time,
not the entire input file.

#### Poor naming

The file handles are very poorly named.
`handleone` and `handletwo` don't convey that one is for input the other is for output.

`ArrayItem` doesn't follow the recommended naming convention of `snake_case` (see [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)),
and it doesn't describe what it really is.

But `f1` wins the trophy of worst name in the posted code.
`lines` would have been better.

#### Minor optimization

Instead of re-evaluating regular expressions in every loop,
I use `re.compile` to compile them first, to make all uses efficient.
However, this might not be necessary,
as it seems recent versions of Python have a caching mechanism.

#### Suggested implementation

With the above suggestions applied, the code becomes simpler and cleaner:

```
import re

re_pattern = re.compile(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+')

with open("input.txt") as fh_in:    
    with open("mailout.txt", "a+") as fh_out:
        for line in fh_in:
            match_list = re_pattern.findall(line)
            if match_list:
                fh_out.write(match_list[0]+"\r\n")
```

Comment: See [_Multiple variables in Python 'with' statement_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/893333/1157100).